# How to skip second activity when there is no data in database using adapter class and recyclerview?

Tags: android

Example:

This is a Main Activity and onclick item from adapter class its open second activity having listview but in case there is no data in listview for any of the item of grid activity then skip second activity and goto third activity directly. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrbTJ.jpg

[1]: [Second Activity][1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEfEF.png

[1]:Third Activity https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSYMB.png

Comment: where did you get data to listview, in Activity-One or Activity-Two?

Comment: In Activity-Two

Comment: So you will know that the grid click on Activity-One contain list or not only in Activity-Two?

Comment: Activity-One(Grid click) -> Activity-Two(get data to list - check list size, if list size is greater that 0 then show list else call Activity-3)

Comment: But it shows Activity-Two blank for few seconds and then call Activity-Three

Comment: No progress loading?

Comment: if(ModelList.size()!=0) {
                    ListAdapter = new ListAdapter(ModelList, getApplicationContext());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(ListAdapter);
                    ListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
              else {
                 Intent intent=   new Intent(ListActivity.this,StoryActivity.class);
                 intent.putExtra("title",title);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }

Comment: what issue in this?

Comment: I have used this code and it works fine for me.But I want to avoid  blank page in Activity-two and directly go to third activity if list size is 0

Comment: It takes some time to check whether list size is 0 or not.

Comment: Then you need to call the method for getting list corresponding to clicked Grid in Activity-One itself and now check the size of list in Act-One and do the rest as same. Pass the value to Act-2 or Act-3.(Until getting data to list show loading)

Comment: @developer The blank activity is caused by data fetching duration, not checking the list size. So, it seems you should not start second activity before data loaded. Loading and checking data size in activity-one make scene in your situation.

Comment: How can I check this in activity-one ?

Comment: The same way you used in Activity-Two to fetch data for the clicked grid item

Comment: you may pass some values like id from clicked grid to fetch data

Comment: Okay ,Let me try this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand what you mind in the comment section, this follow would be ok:

**In Activity-One:**

When the user clicks an item -> fetch data & show loading. When data fetching ends, hide loading and check data size to decide starting activity second or the third one.

Comment: I am not using loading , directly load data without any loading progress bar.

Comment: @developer, thus in data loading time, what you want users to see on your app's screen?

Comment: Is it mandatory , I am new to android so, I don't have any idea about it.

Comment: It's not mandatory but it's recommended. If you still don't want to show any loading view on screen while data is loading, your app would look freeze (because data need a duration to be loaded) when user click the items even when you try the way recommended by @Arnold Brown.

Comment: Okay,I will try both. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible directly, You need to know before if there is data in list or not or you need to move to secondactivity ofr 1 sec and then can navigate further.It will look like skip.